# Windows 2008 Runlevel Scripts on Shutdown. Is it possible?

Tags: windows, script, reboot, runlevel

When Windows 2008 gets shutdown or rebooted [not via a script] by someone, is there a way to have a pre-processing script executed similar to UNIX runlevel scripts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### When Windows is shutdown or rebooted is there a way to execute a script?

> Execute gpedit.msc (local Policies)
>
> Windows settings -> Scripts -> Shutdown -> Properties -> Add

Source http://stackoverflow.com answer [How to schedule a task to run when shutting down windows](https://stackoverflow.com/a/101676/3536342) by Dan Williams.